# Reading totalsupply of a token on BSC Smart Contract from a ETH Smart Contract

Tags: interop, ethereum, smartcontracts, binance-smart-chain, evm

My BSC smart contract needs to know the totalsupply of another token on an ETH smart contract. It seems difficult to read blockchain data between smart contract networks. Does anyone know how you can read the totalsupply of tokens that share the same address between EVM compatible smart contract networks?

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone know how you can read the totalsupply of tokens that share the same address between EVM compatible smart contract networks?

Currently there is no way to do it.

You need to pass this information off-chain.

Generally, any read call or transaction across different networks is not possible without some sort of centralised bridge or oracles.